# How does Enzyme work together with Jest when testing React components?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am using Enzyme with a create-react-app, and I'm a little confused as to how exactly they interplay. Am I using Enzyme API in my assertions, or Jest's, or a combination of both?

For instance, this is my test code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Console from './Console';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';

it('renders', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Console />);

  expect(wrapper.equals(<div id="console" />)).toBe(true);
});
```

`.equals()` seems to be an [Enzyme API](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/equals.html), but I can't find .toBe()` anywhere in Enzyme's API documentation.

On a broader note, how exactly do test runners, frameworks, and assertion libraries interact? I've read multiple articles and SO questions and answers, but I'm still not too sure. Thank you!

Comment: expect here is being used from jest and not enzyme Check https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html

Comment: In that case, why do I not need to import or require 'jest' in my test file? I'm only importing 'shallow' from the 'enzyme' module - doesn't this mean I'm only restricted to enzyme APIs under  'shallow'?

Comment: that is because when you configure jest, it adds a list of global apis, check . https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/api.html